# flutter_search_bar plugin onClose listener

Tags: dart, flutter

I am currently using flutter_search_bar plugin with a Tabbed Pages. Since my values change dynamically. I was wondering if there were any ways to add a listener to the package in order to make the necessary changes.

The plugin is here:
https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/packages?q=flutter_search_bar&api=0

Update: this is what my code looks like now

```
  _NavigationState() {
    searchBar = new SearchBar(
      controller: controller,
      inBar: false,
      setState: setState,
      onSubmitted: onSubmit,
      onChanged: onChange,
      buildDefaultAppBar: buildAppBar,
      hintText: 'Search Book',
      closeOnSubmit: false,
      clearOnSubmit: true,
      onClosed: onClosed,
    );
  }

  void onClosed() {
    isSeaching = false;
    loadTabpages();
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fork the repo and make the changes :

https://github.com/ArcticZeroo/flutter-search-bar/blob/master/lib/src/flutter_search_bar_base.dart

Add this var in SearchBar class:

```
     /// Event triggered when the user close the search bar
      final VoidCallback onClosed;
```

Add the field into the constructor

```
      SearchBar(
          {@required this.setState,
          @required this.buildDefaultAppBar,
          this.onSubmitted,
          this.controller,
          this.hintText = 'Search',
          this.inBar = true,
          this.colorBackButton = true,
          this.closeOnSubmit = true,
          this.clearOnSubmit = true,
          this.showClearButton = true,
          this.onChanged,
          this.onClosed})
```

Line 144

Set a widget into the leading property

```
         new IconButton(
                  icon: const BackButtonIcon(),
                  color: buttonColor,
                  tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).backButtonTooltip,
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (onClosed != null) {
                      onClosed();
                    }
                    Navigator.maybePop(context);
                  }),
```

Using the listener:

```
    new SearchBar(
            inBar: true,
            setState: setState,
            showClearButton: false,
            clearOnSubmit: false,
            closeOnSubmit: false,
            onClosed: () {

            }), ...
```

**Updated handling the back button**

```
    return new AppBar(
          leading: WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () {
              if (onClosed != null) {
                onClosed();
              }
              return Future.value(true);
            },
            child: new IconButton(
                icon: const BackButtonIcon(),
                color: buttonColor,
                tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).backButtonTooltip,
                onPressed: () {
                  if (onClosed != null) {
                    onClosed();
                  }
                  controller.clear();
                  Navigator.maybePop(context);
                }),
          ),

          ....
```

Comment: Were you able to successfully test the changes?

Comment: my onClose method just never seems to be hit, when I run it

Comment: did you copy the searchbar class into your project and modified it? could you update your question with your code?

Comment: oh wait, the onClosed method is called when your press the button at the top-left .  is it ok? or you want to call it when you press back on android

Comment: when you press the back button, the implementation you proposed seemed correct. Thats why I am confused as to why It is not hitting onClosed()

Comment: It works, but one, edit onWillPop should return Future<bool>.value(true). I can make the edit for you. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Nice work @diegoveloper. You can raise a PR to `flutter-search-bar` so that it will be used by many people.